# How to bind a same path to two component, depending the user role

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I struggle with Angular routes (v14)

I want to bind two components to a same pat. The user have to fall in one of them depending his roles.

I tried something like this but it didn't work.

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { RoleGuard } from '.guard';
import { MyComponent } from './components';

const routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      { path: '', component: MyComponent, canActivate: [RoleGuard], data: { roles: ['RoleA'] } },
      { path: '', component: MyComponent, canActivate: [RoleGuard], data: { roles: ['RoleB'] } }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class SubModule { }
```

I didn't find a solution to fix this problems,
I know i can use *ngIf on my templates but i don't want to because in future, there will be many differents views per user role.
do you guys have any solutions/alternatives ?

Comment: Maybe [this question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75732477/angular-14-routes-add-dynamic-loadcomponent-import-url-with-variable/75733775#75733775) will be helpful.

Comment: I would use `canMatch` for those purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this way:

1. **Role Service**: Create a service to manage the user's role.

```js
// role.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class RoleService {
  private role: string;  // Assume role can be 'RoleA' or 'RoleB'

  constructor() { }

  setRole(role: string): void {
    this.role = role;
  }

  getRole(): string {
    return this.role;
  }
}
```

2. **Role-based Route Guard**: Create a route guard that checks the user's role and redirects accordingly.

```js
// role.guard.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { RoleService } from './role.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class RoleGuard implements CanActivate {
  
  constructor(private roleService: RoleService, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    const role = this.roleService.getRole();
    if (role === 'RoleA') {
      return this.router.parseUrl('/role-a');
    } else if (role === 'RoleB') {
      return this.router.parseUrl('/role-b');
    }
    return false;
  }
  
}
```

3. **Routing Module**: Modify your routing module to include the new routes for `RoleAComponent` and `RoleBComponent`.

```js
// routing.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { RoleAComponent } from './role-a/role-a.component';
import { RoleBComponent } from './role-b/role-b.component';
import { RoleGuard } from './role.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', canActivate: [RoleGuard] },  // This will redirect based on role
  { path: 'role-a', component: RoleAComponent },
  { path: 'role-b', component: RoleBComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

With this setup, when the user navigates to the root path (`''`), the `RoleGuard` will be activated. Based on the user's role, the guard will redirect to either `/role-a` or `/role-b`, rendering the appropriate component for the user's role.